# Правильное расставление роутов, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

у меня как-то криво сделано мне кажется `Route::resource` в laravel. Подскажите как грамотно расставить.
 **Ошибка**: заключается в том, что у меня после /article/  - можно указать любой url, и не выдает ошибку, то есть можно article/test и все также выдает этот же шаблон

```
/*Роуты*/
            Route::resource("/article","Action\ArticleController");
            Route::post("/article/create","Action\ArticleController@add");

            Route::get("/article/edit","Action\ArticleController@edit");
            Route::put("/article/{id?}/edit","Action\ArticleController@update");
```

Контроллеры: (public function index() - пока что нет)

```
   /**
     * Get запрос
     * отображает добавление статьи
     */

 public function create()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Post запрос
     * добавляет статью
     */
    public function add(Request $request)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get запрос
     * Отображает все доступные статьи,которые можно отредактировать
     */
    public function show($id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get запрос 
     * Редактирует выбранную статью
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Put запрос
     * Редактирование статьи
     *
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

    }
```

Comment: "то есть можно article/test и все также выдает этот же шаблон" - какой этот же? Что-то я не пойму суть проблемы

Comment: Уже неактуально, решил сам

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
Route::put("/article/{id}/edit","Action\\ArticleController@update")->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Я надеюсь, из примера понятно, что id в данном случае - это число.

Comment: Это хорошо конечно, но мне надо исправить. 
Ошибка: заключается в том, что у меня после /article/ - можно указать любой url, и не выдает ошибку, то есть можно article/test и все также выдает этот же шаблон

Answer (score -2):

попробуйте так прописать роут и в контролере получить параметр `$id`

```
Route::resource("/article/{id?}","Action\ArticleController");
```